# Not able to connect to ActiveMq installed in remote machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-batch, spring-jms

I am trying to connect to ActiveMq which is installed in remote machine.But i am not connect to Queue from one system to another which is in same network.Can someone help me solving this

**[t#0.container-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'requestsQueue'**

Comment: Post you code/configuration

Comment: Make sure it's listening on the IP address you want to connect to - `netstat -lntp` on linux `netstat -ano` on Windows. If it is, then it might be a firewall issue.

Comment: i am able to connect to it if am running on same machine.I am not connect to it from any other system in same network